# Is there any gourmet rice cooking method where you don’t rinse the rice?

Tags: rice

I’m curious if there’s any culinary tradition that chooses not to rinse rice because of a desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

An example would be Paella - the dry rice is either added to the hot liquid or gently cooked in the oil and aromatics until translucent, then liquid etc. is added.
The latter principle is also used for risotto.

Cooks claim it’s to retain that extra bit of starch to get the desired creaminess in the dish.

Comment: Somehow missed that you had risotto in there.  You might be able to get paella for work with a washed rice.  (It’d be more pilaf-like, though).  You’d have to really beat up risotto to get a creamy consistency at the end of it was washed first